# Using XLConnect to read in xls

Tags: r, excel

I'm using the following code to try and read in an old `xls` file

```
library("XLConnect")
path <- "C:/Users/foo/Desktop/WEEK 17.xls"
df <- readWorksheet(path, sheet = 1)
```

i get the following error

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readWorksheet’ for signature ‘"character", "numeric"’

Does anyone know why?
I can open the file in excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It s because `readWorksheet` use `workbook` as `object`.

You have to

```
# Load workbook
wb <- loadWorkbook("C:/Users/foo/Desktop/WEEK 17.xls")
```

and then

```
df <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = 1)
```

or use 
`readWorksheetFromFile("C:/Users/foo/Desktop/WEEK 17.xls", sheet = 1)`

Which realy do the same

```
> XLConnect::readWorksheetFromFile
function (file, ...) 
{
    args <- list(...)
    args$object <- loadWorkbook(file, create = FALSE)
    do.call("readWorksheet", args)
}
<environment: namespace:XLConnect>
```